# Why max-width:97.5% on content images?

Tags: theme-development, css, theme-twenty-eleven

Is there a specific reason why we find `max-width:97.5%` instead of `100%` in common themes such as Twenty Eleven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the TwentyEleven theme also includes some default padding and a border for (fluid) images (see CSS below), a width of 100% would push the image outside of its container's width. This is because of how the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) works: border and padding are added to the width/height.

```
img[class*="align"], img[class*="wp-image-"], #content .gallery .gallery-icon img {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

A better solution would be to change the box model calculation for images in this case. A CSS3 property called [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) is available for that.

```
img.size-full, img.size-large {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
            box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Note: [`box-sizing` does not work in Internet Explorer 7 or lower](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing).